# i am have problem with validation to the codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-4

hello when try save a form with codeigniter 4 not save, this occurs when try add a validation to the controller

hello i am have this function

```
public function create_user()
    {
        if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post' && $this->validate([
            'nombre' => 'required',
            'apellido' => 'required',
        ])) {
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre_user'];
            $apellido = $_POST['apellido_user'];
            $data = [
                'nombre' => $nombre,
                'apellido' => $apellido,
            ];
            $user = $this->user = new userModels();
            if ($user->save($data)) {
                return redirect()->to(base_url() . '/gestion-user');
            }
        } else {
            echo view('header');
            echo view('user_form');
            echo view('footer');
        }
    }
```

but not save when try save the form not save, them when quit this line

```
if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post' && $this->validate([
```

save is succesful

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (strtolower($this->request->getMethod() == 'post' && $this->validate([
```